# How to stretch and interpolate array-composed columns in dataframe to get same length arrays for each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a df where two columns are composed by arrays of different length, as you can see in the following table:

| Timestamp | Spotname | CurrentCurve | VoltageCurve | Length_CurrentCurve | Length_VoltageCurve |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-11-26 16:58:25 | 60181_0_00 | [313, 2265, 4181, 5575, 6586, 7213, 7562, 7910, 8050, 7980, 7910, 7945, 7910, 7980, 8084, 8084, 8084, 8189, 8189, 8119, 8154, 8189, 8119, 8084, 8154, 8119, 8119, 8224, 8224, 8154, 8224, 8259, 8189, 8119, 8189, 8189, 8154, 8224, 8189, 8119, 8189, 8224, 8154, 8119, 8189, 8189, 8154, 8224, 8189, 8119, 8189, 8224, 8154, 8119, 8224, 8189, 8189, 8293, 8328, 8259, 8328, 8328, 8259, 8259, 8363, 8293, 8259, 8363, 8363, 8259, 8293, 8363, 8328, 8363, 8433, 8363, 8328, 8433, 8398, 8293, 8363, 8433, 8363, 8293, 8363, 8363, 8363, 8468, 8468, 8363, 8433, 8468, 8398, 8328, 8433, 8398, 8398, 8468, 8468, 8363, 8398, 8468, 8398, 8363, 8433, 8398, 8398, 8468, 8433, 8363, 8433, 8468, 8363, 8363, 8468, 8398, 8328, 8398, 8433, 8398, 8433, 8468, 8363, 8398, 8468, 8433, 8328, 8433, 8433, 8328, 8363, 8433, 8398, 8398, 8468, 8433, 8363, 8468, 8468, 8363, 8398, 8468, 8398, 8398, 8468, 8398, 8328, 8433, 8503, 8398, 8433, 8468, 8398, 8363, 8468, 8468, 8398, 8433, 8468, 8398, 8398, 8468, 8433, 8363, 8433, 8433, 8398, 8503, 8503, 8433, 8468, 8503, 8433, 8398, 8468, 8468, 8363, 8433, 8468, 8433, 8468, 8537, 8468, 8433, 8468, 8468, 8398, 8468, 8503, 8433, 8433, 8468, 8398, 8398, 8537, 8572, 8503, 8503, 8503, 8398, 8433, 8503, 8468, 8363, 8433, 8468, 8433, 8537, 8572, 8503, 8503, 8537, 8468, 8433, 8503, 8503, 8468, 8537, 8537, 8468, 8468, 8537, 8468, 8398, 8503, 8503, 8468, 8537, 8572, 8503, 8503, 8572, 8503, 8468, 8537, 8537, 8468, 8503, 8503, 8468, 8537, 8642, 8572, 8537, 8572, 8572, 8503, 8572, 8642, 8537, 8503, 8572, 8572, 8572, 8677, 8642, 8572, 8642, 8642, 8572, 8572, 8642, 8572, 8503, 8607, 8607, 8607, 8677, 8747, 8642, 8642, 8747, 8677, 8642, 8712, 8712, 8642, 8712, 8747, 8642, 8677, 8747, 8677, 8607, 8677, 8712, 8677, 8747, 8781, 8677, 8712, 8781, 8712, 8642, 8747, 8712, 8607, 8677, 8747, 8677, 8712, 8781, 8712, 8677, 8747, 8712, 8642, 8747, 8781, 8677, 8642, 8747, 8712, 8712, 8747, 8712, 8642, 8747, 8816, 8712, 8712, 8781, 8747, 8607, 8712, 8747, 8712, 8816, 8851, 8747, 8747, 8816, 8747, 8677, 8781, 8781, 8747, 8781, 8816, 8747, 8747, 8816, 8747, 8677, 8747, 8781, 8712, 8816, 8816, 8747, 8747, 8816, 8747, 8677, 8781, 8781, 8677, 8712, 8816, 8747, 8781, 8851, 8781, 8712, 8816, 8781, 8712, 8781, 8816, 8712, 8712, 8816, 8781, 8781, 8816, 8781, 8712, 8816, 8851, 8781, 8747, 8816, 8781, 8781, 8851, 8851, 8781, 8851, 8851, 8781, 8781, 8781, 8677, 8747, 8851, 8816, 8781, 8851, 8851, 8781, 8781, 8816, 8781, 8712, 8781, 8816, 8747, 8851, 8886, 8781, 8781, 8851, 8781, 8747, 8816, 8816, 8712, 8781, 8851] | [144, 815, 1356, 1666, 1818, 1839, 1796, 1767, 1688, 1565, 1486, 1435, 1385, 1378, 1378, 1356, 1349, 1363, 1356, 1327, 1334, 1349, 1327, 1306, 1334, 1334, 1334, 1378, 1356, 1349, 1349, 1356, 1334, 1313, 1334, 1334, 1334, 1356, 1349, 1334, 1356, 1363, 1349, 1356, 1385, 1385, 1385, 1414, 1407, 1407, 1435, 1464, 1443, 1457, 1493, 1493, 1479, 1515, 1515, 1486, 1515, 1515, 1486, 1493, 1515, 1508, 1486, 1529, 1515, 1486, 1508, 1529, 1515, 1515, 1544, 1515, 1508, 1536, 1529, 1493, 1515, 1536, 1508, 1486, 1529, 1529, 1515, 1558, 1536, 1515, 1529, 1544, 1529, 1508, 1536, 1529, 1529, 1544, 1536, 1515, 1529, 1536, 1515, 1508, 1536, 1529, 1529, 1544, 1529, 1508, 1536, 1536, 1515, 1508, 1536, 1529, 1493, 1529, 1536, 1529, 1536, 1536, 1515, 1515, 1544, 1529, 1508, 1536, 1536, 1508, 1515, 1536, 1529, 1536, 1558, 1529, 1515, 1544, 1536, 1508, 1529, 1544, 1529, 1529, 1544, 1529, 1493, 1536, 1544, 1529, 1536, 1544, 1529, 1515, 1544, 1536, 1529, 1536, 1536, 1515, 1529, 1544, 1529, 1515, 1536, 1536, 1529, 1544, 1544, 1536, 1536, 1558, 1529, 1515, 1544, 1536, 1515, 1529, 1544, 1536, 1536, 1558, 1536, 1515, 1544, 1536, 1508, 1536, 1544, 1529, 1529, 1536, 1515, 1515, 1565, 1565, 1536, 1544, 1544, 1515, 1529, 1544, 1529, 1508, 1529, 1536, 1529, 1565, 1565, 1544, 1544, 1565, 1536, 1529, 1558, 1544, 1544, 1565, 1573, 1536, 1558, 1573, 1544, 1536, 1565, 1565, 1558, 1587, 1594, 1573, 1573, 1594, 1573, 1565, 1587, 1587, 1565, 1587, 1587, 1565, 1594, 1623, 1609, 1594, 1616, 1594, 1587, 1616, 1623, 1594, 1587, 1616, 1616, 1616, 1645, 1637, 1616, 1637, 1637, 1616, 1623, 1645, 1623, 1594, 1637, 1637, 1637, 1666, 1674, 1645, 1645, 1666, 1645, 1637, 1666, 1659, 1637, 1666, 1666, 1637, 1645, 1666, 1637, 1623, 1659, 1666, 1637, 1666, 1674, 1645, 1659, 1674, 1645, 1637, 1666, 1659, 1623, 1637, 1666, 1645, 1659, 1674, 1645, 1637, 1666, 1659, 1637, 1659, 1666, 1623, 1623, 1666, 1645, 1645, 1659, 1645, 1616, 1659, 1674, 1637, 1645, 1666, 1637, 1609, 1645, 1659, 1637, 1666, 1666, 1637, 1637, 1666, 1637, 1616, 1659, 1645, 1623, 1659, 1659, 1623, 1623, 1659, 1623, 1609, 1637, 1637, 1623, 1659, 1659, 1623, 1637, 1659, 1623, 1609, 1637, 1637, 1609, 1616, 1645, 1623, 1637, 1659, 1623, 1609, 1637, 1637, 1609, 1637, 1645, 1609, 1609, 1637, 1623, 1616, 1637, 1623, 1609, 1637, 1645, 1616, 1609, 1623, 1609, 1609, 1637, 1623, 1609, 1623, 1637, 1594, 1609, 1609, 1573, 1594, 1623, 1616, 1594, 1623, 1616, 1587, 1594, 1616, 1587, 1565, 1609, 1609, 1587, 1616, 1616, 1587, 1594, 1609, 1587, 1565, 1594, 1587, 1565, 1573, 1594] | 2513 | 2512 |

I have to interpolate each row where length is less than 2540 (which is the maximum length).
I thought about filling NaN first but still I don't find a way to fill arrays of different length.
Thank you to anyone who will try to answer!

Comment: Can you replace your image by plain text data, please?

Comment: @Corralien I've tried to add them in a table but they're very long, let me know if it's better. Thank you!

Comment: Questions: What is the type of `CurrentCurve` and `VoltageCurve`: list, ndarray, str? What do you mean by interpolate? Do you want to pad with NaN from 2513 to 2540? It's difficult to interpolate without a reference index.